# String conversion to DateTime not working

Tags: datetime, converters, formatexception

I'm trying to save data of birth in database from client but it gives format exception

heres my conversion

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DateTime.ParseExact(dob.Text ,"dd-mm-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

input example dob.text="22-2-2012"
in this case exception is "String was not recognized as valid dateTime"

but in case of "22-12-2012"
the exception is "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dob.Text, "dd-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

instead (note the single capital M instead of your double small m)

Have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) and look at the difference between a single M and a double M.